# ¿Como cambiar | por , en python ? Valuerror: malformed node or str

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

Hola a todos tengo un problema con este tipo de valor en una de mis columnas `Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi`, quiero convertir ese carácter a coma con python ya que que tengo otro problema con está línea.

```py
# Aplicar el mismo preprocesamiento en los valores de cadena
movies1.genres = movies1.genres.apply(lambda x: list(map(lambda d: list(d.values())[1], ast.literal_eval(x)) if isinstance(x, str) else []))
movies1.genres.head()
```

Luego me sale este error

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.BinOp object at 0x7f60ece85e80>
```

Como puedo solucionarlo Gracias.

Comment: Hola @NatGGScience, si todo lo que necesitas es hacer una cambio de carácter, puedes usar: **palabra = "Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi"
palabraNueva = palabra.replace( "|", "," )**, si no es así, deberías explicar mejor tus necesidades y adjuntar el código que tienes (o la sección del mismo involucrada).

Comment: De paso, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba haciendo lo siguiente:

```
movies1.genres = movies1.genres.apply(lambda x: list(map(lambda d: list(d.values())[1], ast.literal_eval(x.replace("|", ",")) if isinstance(x, str) else []))
movies1.genres.head()
```

Allí compruebo si x es una cadena con `isinstance()` y si es así reemplazo los caracteres '|' por ','. Después se evalúa con ast.literal_eval() para después finalmente aplicar la función list(map(lambda d: list(d.values())[1], ...)) y asi.

Comment: Traté de usarlo pero me siguió saliendo error, así que decidí omitir literal_eval(). Muchas Gracias!! por tu ayuda igual ese código lo guardo para otra parte del proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar el accessor [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) para realizarlo fácilmente.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a|b|c', 'd|e|f', 3, np.nan]})
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str).str.replace('|',',', regex=False)
print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
     col
0  a,b,c
1  d,e,f
2      3
3    nan
```

**Nota importante:** Si no utilizas `astype(str)` e intentas utilizar el accesor directamente en la serie, de esta forma:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('|',',', regex=False)
```

Al encontrarse con valores que no son `string` va a devolver `NaN`, de esta forma (Nota como la tercera fila en lugar de devolver 3 devuelve `NaN`):

```
     col
0  a,b,c
1  d,e,f
2    NaN
3    NaN
```

Esto sucede cuando la columna tiene diferentes tipos de datos como en el ejemplo que mostré. Para evitar ese "problema" ponemos `astype(str)` para decirle a `pandas` que toda la serie se debe interpretar como `strings` y en caso de no encontrar coincidencia va a devolver el contenido original.

Comment: Muchas Gracias este código me funcionó bastante bien!!!

Comment: @NatGGScience, no hay de que, una pregunta, si este código te funcionó y el de la otra respuesta no ¿Por qué aceptaste la otra respuesta?

Comment: Si puedes dale el voto a esta respuesta ya que darmela a mi que no te funciono es injusto